# Just made a chatroom for alternative history

Tags: discussion

Basically, talk about anything you want, as long as it's more-or-less related to the topic.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126931/alternative-history-discussion

Comment: seems it was removed

Comment: I'm afraid that chatrooms are horribly implemented in Stack Exchange.